# Pandas read_csv() - Flie contains different data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Problem:
I am trying to read in a csv to a pandas dataframe that contains data of different column sizes.

Example & Description:

```
Code: 
df = pd.read_csv(input, error_bad_lines=False)

input:
ID, Time, Val
15, 18:00:01, 4
15, 18:00:02, 6
15, 18:00:03, 5
ID, Time, Val1, Val2
16 18:00:03, 1, 43
ID, Time, Val
15, 18:00:04, 8
```

and this pattern continues for the entirety of the file. Originally I was thinking about throwing away the extra columns since read_csv option throws and error and doesn't read them I just started to ignore them. However I then get duplicate headers in my dataframe... To combat this I tried the `drop_duplicates()` but found out that only in V0.17 of pandas do they include the `keep=False` option. I eventually started to convince myself that try to keep the data. So here is my question. Based on the dataset above I was hoping that I might be able to create two unique dataframes. You can assume that the ID will always be unique so you can create N number of frames for the number of different IDs you have. Each ID will not have the same number of headers. Once a different ID is encountered its header will be printed. So for example if we hit another ID 16 its header will be printed prior to the data. And again if we hit another ID 15 its header will be printed prior to its data.

I was thinking maybe to just preprocess the data before I started using dataframes since that is an option. But since I am still fairly new to all that pandas can do, I was hoping maybe some people here would have suggestions before I went ahead and wrote some nasty preprocessing code :). The other thought I had which turns into a question is - For the error_bad_lines, is there a way to save those lines to another dataframe or something else? Additionally, I tell pandas in the read_csv to only look for items that have an ID of X and just do that for all my ID's? I will add that the number of IDs is finite and known.

My current version of pandas is 0.14.

Comment: Just to note that version `0.14` is 3 years old now. If you can - upgrade to the latest.

Comment: I wish I could and have been pushing for it but unfortunately I cannot. So I am stuck trying to make do with what I have :(

Comment: What do you want the dataframe to look like... we can get creative with this!

Answer (score 1):

Note I corrected what I think is a typo in your sample data.

- I split your data with a lookahead regular expression.  I look for newline characters that are followed by `ID`.
- Then parse each element of the list and concatenate.

---

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import re

txt = """ID, Time, Val
15, 18:00:01, 4
15, 18:00:02, 6
15, 18:00:03, 5
ID, Time, Val1, Val2
16, 18:00:03, 1, 43
ID, Time, Val
15, 18:00:04, 8"""

def parse(s):
    return pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), skipinitialspace=True)

pd.concat([parse(s) for s in re.split('\n(?=ID)', txt)])

   ID      Time  Val  Val1  Val2
0  15  18:00:01  4.0   NaN   NaN
1  15  18:00:02  6.0   NaN   NaN
2  15  18:00:03  5.0   NaN   NaN
0  16  18:00:03  NaN   1.0  43.0
0  15  18:00:04  8.0   NaN   NaN
```

---

The above was working with the sample data provided by OP.  If this were in a csv file the solution would look like this

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import re

with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    txt = f.read()

def parse(s):
    return pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), skipinitialspace=True)

pd.concat([parse(s) for s in re.split('\n(?=ID)', txt)])
```

Comment: I think this is the solution I want to pursue but I think I need to clarify one or two things in my problem... First off the txt is a csv file that resides locally. This was previous created. The different IDs are all contained in there. If that is what you were doing then this code isn't working out for me.

Comment: @Sharki I've updated my post.   Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the file as having four columns:

```
df = pd.read_csv(input, names=['id', 'time', 'v1', 'v2'])
```

and filter out the extra headers:

```
df = df[df.id != 'ID']
```

Then your two data sets are simply `df[pd.isnull(df.v2)]` and `df[~pd.isnull(df.v2)]`.

Comment: While I also like this my dataset I provided was a subset of the data. The one ID actually has 10 columns and the other has 12 columns. Additionally, this is just for 1 file. There will be other data sets that I put through this script that have other fields that are unique to it. Therefore I wanted the headers to be automatically read by the df.